# How can I tell my dev environment to always load CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser'?

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I'm running a development environment for (mostly) a CGI app with Linux (openSuse) and Apache. Many of the apps we run used to have [CGI::Carp](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aCarp) 'fatalsToBrowser' all the time, and of course we do not want that in production. So this is about doing it on one machine, but not on another. Thus the dreadful CGI::Carp needs to vanish from the code.

I know I can load modules with -M from the command line. That one is a no-brainer, but doesn't help me. I don't want command line, I want CGI with Apache.

I've learned on [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=958615) that there is something called sitecustomize.pl wich is described in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html). It lets you add code that is executed very early during startup. I could probably use it to add a check for the CGI environment and to load the module.

The doc says I have to check `$Config{usesitecustomize}` to see if my Perl can do that. Unfortunately, `perl -e 'print $Config{usesitecustomize}'` does not yield anything. I've go the feeling that it doesn't even knof `$Config` since that is empty when I Data::Dumper it.

I will have a sysadmin just put something there to check, but that may take some time.

**Is there any other way to have Perl load the CGI::Carp module and import `fatalsToBrowser` every time it is started by Apache?**

Comment: [`use Config;`](http://p3rl.org/Config#EXAMPLE) exports `%Config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a switch to the `vhosts.conf` file for the Apache configuration that tells Perl to always load the module. Since that only affects the development box, it solved the problem:

```
PERL5OPT="-MCGI::Carp=fatalsToBrowser"
```

The `PERL5OPT` variable is described in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Answer (score 2):

The perlrun documentation that you linked to states that the `-f` command line flag disables the execution of the `usesitecuistomize` option *if* the perl in question was compiled to support that (`-Dusesitecustomize`).

This option seems to be meant to do rather global changes to a perl configuration, not to alter the behaviour of perl on a per-site-basis.

You can always decide to conditionally load and import a module, e.g.

```
# CGI::Carp is no pragma, so this works without scoping issues:
BEGIN { eval q{ use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/ } if DEBUG_VERSION };
```

where `DEBUG_VERSION` is set to false on deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that it does that, and that is what I want to do exactly. The machine in question is only used for development. There are multiple users, and I want to enforce this behavior on them for all the applications running there. Legacy ftl... :-/